# Sharepoint 2010 Jquery/knockout.js

Tags: 2010, web-services, jquery, active-directory

Bit of background, we have a large SharePoint environment (500k users) which has multiple authentication providers (AD/Custom Claims) in order to simplify user management, I wrote a farm solution which unify's management of them all under one interface available through Central Admin.

This tool has been working smoothly for the past year, but I recently started requirements gathering for version 2, and the feedback was pretty unanimous, everyone hates the UI. When asking the users for examples of what they want the UI to be like, most of the response pointed to sites which are single page applications based off of javascript.

Unfortunately my dev background is desktop applications, so I have little experience with javascript, and non with any of the popular modules which seem to be widely used to implement single page apps.

Having spent the past few days searching the internet, I've come across loads of examples using jquery/knockout.js/backbone.js in SharePoint, but all of them assume you are querying the SharePoint REST api or some other web service.

The problem is, that the current user tool exposes all its methods through standard asp/c# so their is no web service involved.

So my question: Is it possible to use jquery/knockout.js/backbone.js without a webservice to query in sharepoint 2010, E.G rendering a list of objects returned from a method. If so does anyone have an example. If not, do I have to rewrite the entire tool into a webservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way client-side code communicates to the server is through web service calls so you're going to have to do something. My suggestion is to create a WCF REST service that just wraps your existing API. Unless you're dealing with complex data structures it shouldn't be too much work.